# How to bulk convert .pst to individual mails and folder structure?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pst, bulk

I want to convert a few .pst files that I have, to individual emails, in a more open/widely accepted format, and also to maintain the hierarchical folder structure.

Are you aware of a free way of achieving it?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite some time ago *(details forgotten, has probably changed some)* I used gmail as intermediate storage to transfer PST-file content to Thunderbird.

Method outline:

- Create gmail account and make it be usable from within Outlook (still
  possible?)
- Copy your emails (pst file content) to the gmail account creating an intermediate copy.
- Shut down Outlook
- Use another email client, e.g. Thunderbird (using a more "open"
  format ?)
- connect to gmail-account
- transport (copy) emails to the new email client.
- remove intermediate copy from gmail.

*Assuming that Outlook EXPORT-functions does not support the same procedure; Outlook not available at my current location.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The only problem is that I have quite a few very large .pst files that I want to cleanup, so I cannot do it via gmail.

Comment: "quite a few" - well, if the size is a problem -> split the files. Large amounts of data will always be a problem when you need to process the data in any way. Most often there is no convenient tools, as the situation is "unusual". Simply moving the data can be a problem (e.g. I have a large private collection of photos, hardware updates => must move => 2-3 day or longer process even with fast HDDs)

Comment: you gave me an idea. What if i create a local email server instead of gmail? I would have no 15GB limit that gmail has, no upload speed limitation and no data sharing with Google. Finally, I would let Thunderbird take care of the export.

Answer (score 0):

PST file can only be opened as hierarchical folder structure in Outlook client, I'm afraid there is no such way to directly convert PST file to other format.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/236b75b7-f9db-4074-ad7f-fd875682e1a5/how-to-view-pst-file-without-microsoft-outlook?forum=outlook

Comment: The specification is public: https://wiki.fileformat.com/email/pst/